# Browserify jQuery is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, browserify

So I know how to manually fix this but it's annoying!

I included bootstrap dropdown.js and at the end of the function is

`}(jQuery);`

Inside my shim I set jquery as a dependency

```
'bootstrap': {
    "exports": 'bootstrap',
    "depends": {
        "jquery": '$'
    }
},
```

It seems like this is the only way to use `$`, but since the dropdown has jQuery at the end the console shows

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

}(jQuery);
```

Changing it to `}($);` works.

So my question is does anyone have any idea to better do this without manually doing it, or is manually editing the script the best?

Comment: If I had to guess, changing the 'jquery': '$' to 'jquery': 'jQuery' might help.  However, I'd love to know the answer for certain.

Comment: will you please add some detail code over here.this is happen when jquery file we include is not proper.

Comment: @Mahipat it really can be a pain, I know how you feel. What I did was edit the actual plugin script. I don't prefer this method, but it works. Most plugins are written with a self invoking function `(function($){ 
  $.fn.function_name = function(x){};

})(jQuery);` That code allows the jQuery keyword to be used with `$`, but for some reason I have to manually change `(jQuery)` to `($)`. I didn't give it much thought after it worked, but perhaps I should re think this.

Comment: just use this `window.jQuery = require('jquery.js');`

Answer (score 11):

You can use `global.jQuery = require("jquery")`

This is my shim :

```
},
"plugin": {
    "exports": "plugin",
    "depends": [
        "jquery: $",
        "bootstrap: bootstrap"
    ]
}
```

and inside of plugin.js :

```
var $ = require('jquery')(window);
global.jQuery = require("jquery");
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
var plugin = require('plugin');

plugin();
```

it solve my problem. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I found if using `$` does not work then using `jQuery` in the shim instead usually fixes it. Definitely going to refer to this if that ever fails.

Comment: 2018 and this still works. how can I setup a shim file like yours? and what are the advantages?

Answer (score 1):

**Shim**
    "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js": {
      "exports": "$"
    }

**requiring**
    var jQuery = $ = require('$');

This should cover both plugins that use

```
(function($){
 $.fn.function_name = function(x){};
})($);
```

as well as

```
(function($){
  $.fn.function_name = function(x){};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think my solution is anywhere near optimal or ideal and it doesn't answer my question but if anyone has this issue just do it this way, you can get it working possibly as a temporary solution to get things going without stagnating on your project.

Most if not all jQuery plugins are written with a self invoking function like this.

```
(function($){
  $.fn.function_name = function(x){};

})(jQuery);
```

I simply went into the plugin itself and changed `(jQuery)` to `($)`

```
(function($){
  $.fn.function_name = function(x){};

})($);
```

If you're still having problems, make sure you have a shim defined in your package.json file and you are including the jQuery plugin with a require statement.